# Problem passing in Func as parameter to Where clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have this simple 2 lines of following code. It compiles fine but never return results in the datagridview. If I change func to `p=> p.PTNT_FIRST_NAME.StartsWith(this.textBox1.Text)`, it works just fine. What's the problem here?

```
Func<PATIENT, bool> func = (PATIENT p) => p.PTNT_FIRST_NAME.StartsWith(this.textBox1.Text);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataContext.PATIENTs.Where<PATIENT>(func).Select(q => q);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `Func<PATIENT, bool>` to `Expression<Func<PATIENT, bool>>`.

Comment: What's the root cause of this. Why it compiles in the first place?

Comment: It compiles to a normal LINQ call, not LINQ-to-SQL.   LINQ-to-SQL is a set of extension methods that take `Expresion<T>`'s, so you need to pass `Expression<T>`'s to them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Expression<Func<PATIENT, bool>> func = (PATIENT p) => p.PTNT_FIRST_NAME.StartsWith(this.textBox1.Text);
```